# Is there a quick way to change the underlying image in a .snag Snagit file?

Tags: screenshot

I'm using Snagit for user guide screenshots. (New to it, but so far it's great!). I save the screenshot as a layered .snag file, then export .png files for putting into the document. The layers in the .snag file consist of the underlying raster image (the background) plus a layer of annotations and callouts on top.

Doing it this way lets me move and edit the annotations and callouts with ease, then export a replacement .png file. But what if I have a bunch of callouts on a screenshot and the screen itself changes?

Is there a way to replace the raster layer (background) with a new one, while keeping the callouts in place, so I don't have to create a new .snag file? (I want to avoid copying and pasting the callouts from the existing file into a newly created one...)

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible, as long as your annotations and callouts are still vector objects. Here's what you need to do:

1. Delete the existing screenshot.
2. Make a new screenshot and paste it into the snag file.
3. Select the screenshot and use the **Send to Back** function to move it to the bottom layer.
4. If required, adjust the positions of your annotations.